# Visual Studio 2015 and Angular2 Release version errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015

I walked through the Angular 2 Tour of Heroes sample application using the newly released Angular 2 version and hosting it in a Visual Studio 2015 Empty Web application.  Since I followed along with the sample from Angular I'm not using anything specific to Visual Studio or .NET.

The only thing that is a little different from the sample application is the package.json pulls the information into the node_modules directory (like normal), but Visual Studio uses a wwwroot directory as the root directory, so I created a gulp task to copy the node_modules directory from the root of the VS project into the wwwroot directory.

When I run the application everything works as expected, but in Visual Studio when I run the application it says there are 70+ build errors (I can say just ignore those and the site comes up and works correctly).  If I look at the errors they are all pointing to the node_modules directory in the root of the project, which I really just want to ignore.

The Errors that I'm getting are all like:
TS2304  Build:Cannot find name 'Set'
TS2304  Build:Cannot find name 'Promise'
TS2304  Build:Cannot find name 'Map'
etc.

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the error messages?

Comment: Maybe your typings file isn't correct, and it work because the ts file are already compiled to js files? I used vs2015 for a  short while with angular2 but switched to vscode. I really would recommend vscode for angular2 devs. But that's not an answer to your question :-)

Comment: Error Messages provided at the end of the question

Comment: Typings.json file added to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need a `tsconfig.json` file in your solution:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have one already.  I don't know what happened, but all of the build errors went away now.

Comment: Ah, you had to wait, so that the dependencies are downloaded

Comment: No the dependencies were all downloaded and it wasn't working.  It wasn't working for several hours.